# changing server side value in mvc and reloading view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi all: I have a condition in mmy MVC view like this:

if (Profile.visStats == 0)

```
 <img id="image1" alt="" class="statbackground" src="leftblueFolder.png"/>
```

else

```
 <img id="image2" alt="" class="statbackground" src="rightblueFolder.png"/>
```

This works fine.

Now I have two link buttons

```
<a id="visGamebut" runat="server"  >Game</a>
<a id="visSeasonbut" runat="server">Season</a>
```

1) onclick visGamebut I want to make Profile.visStats = 1 and show image2 How to do this

Comment: Since you are using asp.net mvc, is there any reason you have the `runat="server"`?

Comment: What is the `Profile` object? Is it a data object? stored in the session? something else?

Comment: Hi @Scrum meister: Profile is saved in db like this: <profile> <properties><add name="visStats" type="UInt16" defaultValue="0" allowAnonymous="true" /> </properties></profile>

Comment: Hi @Scrum meister: I can remove runat= server from hrefs

Comment: Hi @The Sreum Meister: any hint for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a controller called `ProfileController`. Add a method that will handle the update from the client:

```
public JsonResult UpdateStats()
{
    Profile profile = fetch profile from somewhere;
    profile.visStats = 1;
    //save to db
    return Json(new {result = true});
}
```

In your view, add the folowing code inside a `<script>` tag, that will perform the ajax call:

```
$(function(){ //code should run on document load
  $('#visGamebut').click(function(){ //Attach click handler to the visGamebut link
    $.post('/Profile/UpdateStats', function(data){ //Perform ajax call to the server
      if(data.result){ 
        $(this).unbind('click'); //Unbind the click hander, not to run again on future clicks
        $('#image1').attr('src', 'rightblueFolder.png'); //update img source to image2
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Note: You may want to pass some kind of ID to the server, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Profile is not avaiable in controller. How to access it in Controller. It is available in view only

Comment: @asif Then you got some big problems. Where does the view get it from? Are you **really** using MVC?

Comment: Hi Scrum: When I write  profile.visStats in view, I get intellisence but when i write this in controller, I font get it.

Comment: @asif Do me (and the others who answered/commented to your previous questions) a favor, watch [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs) on ASP.NET MVC. It is an understatement to say you are missing basic fundamental knowledge of the MVC framework, and that is not something we can teach you here at SO.